# Is it possible to use OpenWire protocol with spring-boot-starter-artemis?

Tags: jms, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I set up ActiveMQ Artemis consumer using `spring-boot-starter-artemis` and JMS. I also launched broker locally and I aim to configure these to communicate over OpenWire protocol. To constrain communication to that protocol I modified acceptor in `broker.xml` (protocols=OPENWIRE). It looks like that:

```xml
<acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false</acceptor>
```

However, unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ219013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]
```

**How can I configure the client to use OpenWire protocol?**

What is the default protocol they communicate on? Before I constrained the communication, Artemis Console was presenting the connection has been established on CORE protocol, which as far as I understand collective protocol. Which one i target protocol they really communicate on and how can I check this out?

Comment: Why are you trying to "constrain communication" to just OpenWire? If you do that then only OpenWire JMS clients from ActiveMQ "Classic" will be able to connect.

Comment: What do you mean by "collective protocol"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're receiving `ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException` is because you trying to use `spring-boot-starter-artemis` to connect to an `acceptor` which is configured to *only* support the OpenWire protocol. This will **never** work because [`spring-boot-starter-artemis` depends on `artemis-jms-client`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-artemis/2.7.5/jar) which will *only* use the ActiveMQ Artemis "core" protocol, not OpenWire.

You should configure the `acceptor` in `broker.xml` to support core, e.g.:

```
protocols=CORE,OPENWIRE
```

If you want the client to use OpenWire then you need to use the OpenWire JMS client library from ActiveMQ "Classic."